# How to force crisp edges on text with pixelated fonts

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

I am trying to make something that uses a pixelated font, but I can't seem to get the pixels to stay crisp. When using the pixelated font, it simply adds some kind of anti-aliasing, even though I explicitly want to have it use the crisp pixels.

```css
@import url(https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/d14098fec1a21bb32ccb0ee2ab07bb09?family=Pixelated+Display);

body {
  font-family: "Pixelated Display";
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-smooth: never; /* doesn't work outside macOS */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: none; /* doesn't work outside macOS */
  image-rendering: crisp-edges; /* doesn't affect fonts */
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, CONSECTETUR ADIPISCING ELIT.
```

Above, I included a demo that uses a random pixelated font from the internet ([source](https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/d14098fec1a21bb32ccb0ee2ab07bb09)). However, when taking a screenshot of the result, you can see the text is not crisp like I want, but instead it seems to be smeared out over multiple pixels. To see this more easily, just take a screenshot of the text, then paste it into any image editor, and zoom in. This will result in the following:

[image: What the text looks like]

However, what I want is the pixelated font to be...  pixelated. If I have to use a specific font-size for that, I'm all for it, but so far I haven't been able to find any resources to make this text become crisp, staying pixelated like it should. As you can see in the css of the snippet, the `image-rendering` and `font-smooth` styles do not seem to affect the text at all (at least, not on all operating systems).

A live demo on the website I'm trying to change is [this page](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Template:Quest_reward_scroll), but due to CSP of the site I cannot import the same font onto here. As you can see at the top of the image (which is text that's embedded into the image), the top line is much more crisp than the rest of the image, which is text that's placed on top of the image.

Comment: It might depend on the browser or OS you are using. When you [view the font on the source website](https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/d14098fec1a21bb32ccb0ee2ab07bb09), does it look correct there? When I increase the font size in your demo code the edges look plenty crisp to me. I'm using Firefox on Windows 11.

Comment: Mac OSX here - Chrome -  Very crisp. Struggling to recreate it.

Comment: @ChrisBarr the linked website also doesn't work. In Windows, if you take a screenshot of the demo website (make sure to set the font size to ~10px or so) and then paste that screenshot into an image editing program (e.g. paint). Then zoom in from there. It won't look as crisp. The issue with the source site's font size slider, or editing my code to increase the font size, is that the rendering of the browser won't scale up the same blurriness. However, on displays that have relatively low DPI, it is very visible for smaller fonts that the pixels are slightly blurry.

Comment: I think you are just describing Windows ClearType, which is enabled by default in Windows.  You might want to check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52899904/bypassing-clear-type-on-web-page

Comment: @ChrisBarr I think that's not really the same thing as my issue. That question does want anti aliasing, whereas I actually want to have aliasing (i.e. disable anti aliasing). I've edited my question for a link to a demo on the website I need this for. As you can (probably) see, there is a quite distinct difference between the sharpness of the image's text itself, vs the HTML text placed on top of it. That's because somehow the HTML text has some kind of anti-aliasing effects or blurriness of some sort. That's despite the fact the font itself is perfectly pixelated.

Comment: Hmm yeah I see what you mean, there is for sure a difference. I'm not sure if there's a way to do that, and it may just be an issue with that particular font. If the image of the font is the same I suspect it was "lightened" using photoshop (or something) as it has more options on how to deal with font smoothing.  I'd suggest getting rid of the image and just using the CSS font for all of it so it at least matches